# "ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library" without root access on Linux

Tags: python, shared-libraries, importerror, glfw

I'm trying to run a Python3 code found on GitHub on a remote machine that I don't have root access. The code requires to import `glfw` dependency .

While `pip3 install --user glfw` seems to work perfectly fine (exactly like all the other python dependencies), when I try to run the code I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/ismarou/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/glfw/**init**.py", line 34, in 
>       raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.")
>   ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 9):

You need to install both glfw3 and python bindings for glfw3. With `pip install --user glfw` you installed only the bindings. Now you have to install glfw3 on your system.

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. Installation of `libglfw3` and `libglfw3-dev` solved it.

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
```

Comment: for some reason in my setup python still could not find the glfw shared library. I checked that it can get it via the environment variable `PYGLFW_LIBRARY` and exported the variable to the path: `set -x PYGLFW_LIBRARY /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglfw.so` (in fish shell). It works.

Answer (score 1):

helped the `pip3 install glfw` in the same directory of the build project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tko58.png)

Comment: Can you explain your answer? How does solve the question? How does it differ from other answer?